# Use fetch function within a class?

Tags: javascript, class, async-await, fetch

It returns the `weight` as `undefined` even though it exists in the json file. Even if I make weight an empty object e.g. `this.weight = ''` in constructor it will just log an empty string. Any help?

```js
class Pokemon {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name
    this.init()
  }

  init = () => {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.name}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.name = data.name
      this.weight = data.weight
      this.height = data.height
      this.move = data.moves[0].move.name;
    })
  }
}

(async () => {
  const pika = new Pokemon('pikachu');
  console.log(await pika.height)
})()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `init` returns its Promise, and have `init` be called not from the constructor, but by the caller of `Pokemon`:

```js
class Pokemon {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name
  }

  init = () => {
    return fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.name}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.name = data.name
      this.weight = data.weight
      this.height = data.height
      this.move = data.moves[0].move.name;
    })
  }
}

(async () => {
  const pika = new Pokemon('pikachu');
  pika.init()
    .then(() => {
      console.log(pika.height);
    });
})()
```

If it needs to be used in multiple places, and calling `init` outside isn't suitable, you could also have the constructor assign the Promise to an instance property and chain off of that instead:

```js
class Pokemon {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name
    this.init();
  }

  init = () => {
    this.initProm = fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${this.name}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.name = data.name
      this.weight = data.weight
      this.height = data.height
      this.move = data.moves[0].move.name;
    })
  }
}

(async () => {
  const pika = new Pokemon('pikachu');
  pika.initProm
    .then(() => {
      console.log(pika.height);
    });
})()
```